# Spring 3 -- IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-mvc, illegalstateexception

I am getting an IllegalStateException in my controller.  Here is the mapping and signature for my controller, which is what is relevant here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/poll1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processPoll1(@RequestParam String vote, Model model, BindingResult result) {
```

I am getting the following error, even though my BindingResult argument clearly does follow my Model argument.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be immediately after the model attribute argument in the controller method signature: public java.lang.String com.controller.PollController.processPoll1(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:603)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:859)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:792)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why do you need the model in the parameter? Can you not create a Model in the method? So make it something like --> `(@RequestParam String vote, BindingResult result)`

Comment: I just tried removing the Model, but I got the same error message.  I'm also using the Model to return a cookie to the JSP, so I do have an actual use for it.

Comment: You don`t have to pass a model but you can always return a model with the setup cookie. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the docs:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#d4e13874

BindingResult is only allowed immediately following a command or form object (not Model).